# How to make await function in C# work correctly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a program for Kinect that is supposed to take the Skeletons from 50 frames, calculate the average one and draw it.
An async event handler is added to `SkeletonFrameReady`

> ```
> private async void InitSkeletonEvent(object sender,SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         List<Vector3D> vectors = new List<Vector3D>();
>         double[,] coordinates = new double[50, 3];
>         double[,] finalCoordinates = new double[50, 3];
>
>         using (SkeletonFrame initSkeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
>         {
>             if (initSkeletonFrame != null)
>             {
>                 if (initSkeletons == null)
>                 {
>                     initSkeletons = new Skeleton[initSkeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
>                 }
>                 initSkeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(initSkeletons);
>
>                 Skeleton initSkeleton = initSkeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();
>                 if (initSkeleton != null)
>                 {
>                     foreach (Skeleton s in initSkeletons)
>                     {
>                         // Get all tracked Skeletons for the 50 frames
>                         while (frame < maxFrames)
>                         {
>                             frame += 1;
>
>                             vectors = await getCoordinatesofJoints(initSkeleton);
>
>                             coordinates = await getCoordinatesPerJoint(vectors);
>                         }
>                     }
>                     // Remove the event from SkeletonFrame
>                     this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= InitSkeletonEvent;
>
>                     finalCoordinates = await getAverageCoordinateForJoint(coordinates);
>
>                     skeleton = await getAvgSkeleton(finalCoordinates);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

There are several methods that are called with the `await` parameter. However they do not seem to complete their work and the returned value is not correct.
Here is an example of one of the functions. The rest are written analogically.
Am I using the `async` and `await` incorrectly?

> ```
>  private Task<List<Vector3D>> getCoordinatesofJoints(Skeleton s)
>     {
>         List<Vector3D> vectors = new List<Vector3D>();
>         foreach (Joint j in s.Joints)
>         {
>             Vector3D tmp = new Vector3D(j.Position.X, j.Position.Y, j.Position.Z);
>             vectors.Add(tmp);
>         }
>         return Task.Run(() => vectors);
>     }
> ```

Comment: You should be more specific regarding "they do not seem to complete their work and the returned value is not correct". State exactly what you observe and how that's different from what you expected. Also, what's the point of `return Task.Run(() => vectors);`? All that's going to do is spool up a thread that just returns the list object stored in the `vectors` local variable, which by that time has already been completely initialized. Wouldn't you rather put the whole method body inside the `Run()` method's lambda expression argument, so that the work can be done asynchronously?

Comment: I don't see anything asynchronous in this method. It builds a list of Vector3D synchronously and then wraps it in a Task. Why do you need the Task if you are going to do the work synchronously?

Comment: your method for starters looks like it would need something like the following `static async Task <List<Vector3D>> getCoordinatesofJoints(Skeleton s)` also in your foreach loop you need to assign the await command to something as well

Comment: Can you give me an example how it should be put into the `Run()` method's lambda expression? (lambda expressions are not my strongest side)

Comment: Helena I posted a simple example on how to use or create an async method with Task and await.. as an example to give you an idea of why yours is not async

Comment: @helena.lissenko: Why are you using `async` and `await`?

Comment: Why do you want to put it in a Task to begin with?

Comment: read the following as well to learn about passing async lambda's 
[Potential pitfalls to avoid when passing async lambda's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx)